# Adding code that is not hit at all causes a stack overflow

Tags: .net, vb.net, stack-overflow

Background:

In an application, there is a switch statement that had 160 cases. A developer added 3 more cases, which currently are not hit or used at all. After he added those, we started seeing stack overflow exceptions when hosting the application on IIS with a 256kB stack size. It does not error out when debugging using the built in development server with a 1Mb stack size.

We use a cache system that stores a method call and saves the result from the database in a hash table. The stack overflow exception is happening from there, but we have no idea why. Even trying to view the variable we use to generate the hash key in the debugger causes it to evaluate and causes a stack overflow.

Question:

How can adding code that is not hit cause a stack overflow to occur? 
Is .Net pushing more data to the stack the larger a case statement becomes? 
The fact that it doesn't break at a 1Mb size rules out an infinite recursion loop, doesn't it?

@Blam: Yes, removing or commenting out the three case statements will make it so the error does not occur.

@Kennith, T McKneow: I wish I could post actual code, but its a business application that I've been told cannot be posted online. I can post a summary of the caching process we use, since that is where the error is coming from.

We take f as an expression(Of Func(Of T, TResult)) where T is a BLL class and TResult is whatever is returned from the BLL function.

```
Cast f as a Lambda Expression called body.
Cast body as a MethodCallExpression called MethodExp.
Loop over each Expression in MethodExp.Arguments in a For Each loop with Arg as Expression.
    Dim lArg as LambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(Arg)
    Dim Val as lArg.Compile.DynamicInvoke
    Dim ValStr from Val and use as a part of the Hash Key
```

Update:
The exception is being raised from the lArg.Compile.DynamicInvoke call, and is being raised from mscorlib.dll.

Comment: start with posting some code...

Comment: switch/case blocks are implemented as a lookup table, right? I really doubt the number of cases could give this error.

Comment: Show us some code. Also: burn code which has 160 case statement and try again

Comment: Are you sure something else did not change?  If you take those 3 cases out does the problem go away?

Comment: The added switch cases in and of themselves would not cause additional stack space to be allocated, but local variables added for those new cases might. Perhaps time to extract all those cases into separate methods.

Comment: @Christopherous5000: A bit early for that - he is still around.

Comment: Bertrand Meyer is rolling in his bed at night.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - haha, oops

Answer (score 2):

Even when a section of code in a method is not hit, the compiler will reserve stack space for local variables declared in the code. I've seen this situation occur when the local variables introduced by a new section of code increased the size of the stack frame enough that the same call stack now produces a StackOverflowException.

The following are potential solutions to this problem:

1. Instead of inlining the code for all the cases, create separate methods that implement the switch cases. The downside of this is creating new methods will add stack frames themselves, so focus on extracting code from cases that meet one of the following conditions:

   1. Cases that do not directly or indirectly call the problem method recursively are prime candidates for extraction to a new method.
   2. Cases that declare large numbers of local variables are better candidates for extraction.
   3. Cases that are infrequently hit, or especially cases that are unlikely to appear in a call stack more than once, are good candidates for extraction.
2. Where possible, combine the code from different switch cases when it's possible to reuse local variables.
3. Compile your code with optimizations enabled. The VB compiler *may* combine local variables in a way that reduces the size of your stack frames.
4. Consider converting recursion to iteration using a work list. This moves the allocation overhead you are currently seeing to the heap instead of the stack, potentially fully eliminating the possibility of stack overflow regardless of the number of cases in your switch statement.